# Trying to JSON.parse a file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm downloading a file and trying to use JSON.parse, which should return `{ dateTime: "2012-04-07T17:15:00.000-05:00", value: "1065.91" }` Am I passing the correct object through JSON.parse and structuring it properly?

Code:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
 host: 'waterdata.usgs.gov',
 port: 80,
 path: '/nwis/iv/?sites=02334400&period=P7D&format=json'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
 var responseText = '';
 res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    responseText += chunk;
 });
 res.on('end', function() {
    fs.writeFile('response.txt', responseText.toString(), function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
         console.log('It\'s saved!');
        var d = JSON.parse(responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i < d.value.timeSeries.length; i++) {
            if (d.value.timeSeries[i].variable.variableName == 'Elevation of reservoir      water surface above datum, ft') {
                var result = d.value.timeSeries[i].values[0].value[d.value.timeSeries[i].values[0].value.length - 1];
                console.log(result);
            }
        }
    });
});
}).on('error', function(e) {
console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
```

Comment: The page you're requesting is HTML. You can't parse HTML as JSON.

Comment: Oops, posted the wrong PATH. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `waterdata.usgs.gov` with `waterservices.usgs.gov`